# Como posso encerrar e retomar a gravação de um arquivo usando um único PrintWriter?

Tags: java

Estou trabalhando com um pequeno projeto que realiza a leitura dos dados de uma planilha, visando facilitar a captura das exceptions, tenho uma classe que denomina-se Gerador de Logs.

Esta classe possui um objeto PrintWriter que realiza a escrita dos Throwable que capturo e armazena em um arquivo txt, esse objeto é instanciado quando inicio minha view e encerrado quando realizo o fechamento da mesma, minha intenção é saber se é possível encerrar a gravação do arquivo e retomá-la novamente utilizando o mesmo objeto em tempo de execução?

Minha intenção é disponibilizar um botão que permita a quem utiliza a aplicação ver este arquivo, porém estou meio confuso em como fazer isso já que o arquivo fica aberto para a gravação durante toda a execução da aplicação.

```
package br.com.layoutbuilder.domain;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Date;

public class GeradorLog {

    private PrintWriter out;

    public GeradorLog() {
        try {

            out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("LogAplicativo.txt", true));

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    public void gravaErro(Throwable erro) {

        out.print("Erro ocorrido em: ");
        out.println(new Date());
        out.print("Mensagem de erro: ");
        out.println(erro);
        out.print("Stacktrace: ");
        erro.printStackTrace(out);

    }

    public void close() {

        if (out != null) {
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não há problema em abrir e fechar seu PrintWriter durante a execução do método pois, se o arquivo já existir e o append estiver sinalizado como True (Segundo parâmetro do filewriter), ele vai usar o arquivo que já existe.

```
public gerarLog(Throwable erro) {
    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("LogAplicativo.txt", true));
        out.println("\nErro ocorrido em: " + new Date());
        out.println("Mensagem de erro: " + erro);
        out.print("Stacktrace: ");
        erro.printStackTrace(out);

        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Também existe a opção de usar o Logger do java, dessa forma:

```
public void showErrorMessage(String sourceClass, String sourceMethod, Exception msg){
        try {

            Logger log = Logger.getLogger("My Log");

            Date dt = new Date();
            DateFormat brasil = new SimpleDateFormat ("ddMMyyyy");
            String data = brasil.format(dt);

            // Captura do diretório da aplicação a depender do sistema operacional
            String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");

            // Cria um arquivo log no formato arquivoddmmyyyy
            FileHandler fh = new FileHandler(path+"/biblioteca"+data+".log", true);
            SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter(); 
            fh.setFormatter(formatter);

            // Escreve a mensagem de erro no arquivo
            log.addHandler(fh);
            log.logp(Level.WARNING, sourceClass, sourceMethod, msg.toString());
            fh.close();

        } catch (IOException | SecurityException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } 
    }
```

O arquivo final fica assim:

jun 06, 2017 10:07:26 PM SqlInsert inserirBatch

WARNING: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 1 update movimentacao set exemplar = SINAL VERDE, numero = 1 was aborted: ERROR: syntax error at or near "VERDE"   Position: 42  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.

Comment: Obrigado por esclarecer minha dúvida Gustavo, muito grato!